# how to create edgelist from vector in R

Tags: r

I have a vector like:

```
c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
```

and I'd like to create a dataframe like

```
"from" "to"
A B
B C
C D
D E
E F
```

how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way:

```
data.frame(from = vec[-length(vec)], to = vec[-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method using `embed` and rearranging columns:

```
# data
temp <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")

embed(temp, 2)[, c(2,1)]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "B" 
[2,] "B"  "C" 
[3,] "C"  "D" 
[4,] "D"  "E" 
[5,] "E"  "F"
```

to put this into a data.frame, wrap it in `data.frame:`

```
setNames(data.frame(embed(temp, 2)[, c(2,1)]), c("from", "to"))
  from to
1    A  B
2    B  C
3    C  D
4    D  E
5    E  F
```

Comment: This is why I love this site. Never knew about `embed`.

Answer (score 2):

```
na.omit(data.frame(from = vec, to = dplyr::lead(vec)))
  from to
1    A  B
2    B  C
3    C  D
4    D  E
5    E  F
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `zoo` package,

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(vec, 2, by = 1, paste)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also do:

```
vec <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
x <- rep(seq(length(vec)), each=2)[-length(vec)*2][-1]
# [1] 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6
data.frame(matrix(vec[x], ncol = 2, byrow = T))
```

Or alternatively:

```
data.frame(t(sapply(seq(length(vec)-1), function(i) c(vec[i], vec[i+1]))))

  # X1 X2
# 1  A  B
# 2  B  C
# 3  C  D
# 4  D  E
# 5  E  F
```